# window.open from iframe erases page's contents

Tags: javascript

I have a website with an iframe. In the iframe, I have a button that should, when clicked, open a new browser window to the specified URL. The good news is - it does, the bad news is that on the launching page, all content gets erased (I checked the source code of it and only the closing body and html tags remain). The environment is IE9. I don't want to have to screenshot a button then make it a link and img, I shouldn't have to do that in 2012!!!

Please help!!

The code I'm using is:

```
<button onclick="window.open('admin.php')">ADMIN</button>
```

Comment: The page has PHP in it which is stripped before it gets to the browser, and that's just to display some error message after searching the database. There's no other javascript in the page. I'm a hand coder and have triple checked that there are no missing speech marks or arrows.

Comment: Ok cool, I figured it out. I had the button within a form, removed it from the form and it works like juice.

Comment: You can keep your button in the form, if you want. Just set `type="button"` for your button.

Answer (score 0):

I had the button within a form, removed it from the form and it works like juice.